# Как считать информацию из редактируемого текстового поля после каждого нажатия клавиши?

Tags: javascript

Предположим есть текстовое поле (`input`, `textarea` или `div[contenteditable="true"]` - не важно). Мне необходимо при каждом нажатии клавиши брать оттуда содержимое.

Проблема заключается в том, что событие назначенное таким образом, выполняется раньше, чем событие по умолчанию в браузере (то есть я сначала выкидываю содержимое `textarea` в консоль, а потом только браузер добавляет букву в `textarea`)

```
textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.innerText);
});
```

Что делать, как быть?

p.s. предполагаю, можно использовать `setTimeout`, но этот способ мне очень не нравится. есть ли что-нибудь вроде `callback`-а действий браузера по умолчанию ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У набора событий `key*` есть два достаточно существенных, на мой взгляд, недостатка.

Первый состоит в том, что если пользователь зажмёт клавишу, то пока он её держит, будут генерироваться пары событий `keydown`, `keypress` и только после отпускания возникнет `keyup`. Тем самым после `keyup` мы получим не один добавленный символ, а много.

Второй недостаток заключается в получении нами не только ввода символов, но и нажатий специальных клавиш типа <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> и т.д. Мы получим даже событие нажатия <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.

В связи с этим, возможно, более подходящим будет перехват события `input`.

```js
function onInput() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
    input2.value = input1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" oninput="onInput();"/><br>
<input type="text" id="input2" disabled>
```

Answer (score 6):

По-моему вам просто нужно событие `keyup` вместо `keypress`:

> Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that
>   key has been performed.